# Pivot table with two value columns

Tags: sql-server, excel, pivot, multiple-columns

I can make this work in excel but can't replicate in MSSQL 2012.
Simple table (which in real life is a pivot result itself) that has four columns with the following values:

Region  Risk    Count   Request
North      FM        7      £35930.7
North    SPV 14     £133629.86
Scot        FM      2        £10822.5
Scot     SPV   16     £618555.93
South     FM      2             £544.96
South  SPV   11      £189079.8

Result needs to look like this:

Region   FMCount    FMRequest   SPVCount    SPVRequest
North    7                £35,930.70     14                  £133,629.86 
Scot        2               £10,822.50      16               £618,555.93
 
South     2                    £544.96   11               £189,079.80

Answer (score 0):

Use `Conditional Aggregate`

```
SELECT Region,
       Max(CASE WHEN Risk = 'FM' THEN cnt END) FM_COUNT,
       Max(CASE WHEN Risk = 'FM' THEN request END) FM_REQUEST,
       Max(CASE WHEN Risk = 'SPV' THEN cnt END) SPV_COUNT,
       Max(CASE WHEN Risk = 'SPV' THEN request END) SPV_REQUEST
FROM   Yourtable
GROUP  BY Region
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
a.region, a.FMCount, b.FMRequest, a.SPVCount, b.SPVRequest
from
(
    select
    region, [FM] as FMCount, [SPV] as SPVCount
    from
    (select region, risk, sum(cnt) as cnt from data group by region, risk) a
    pivot (  sum(cnt) for Risk in ([FM], [SPV]) ) a
) a
inner join
(
    select
    region, [FM] as FMRequest, [SPV] as SPVRequest
    from
    (select region, risk, sum(request) as request from data group by region, risk) a
    pivot (  sum(request) for Risk in ([FM], [SPV]) ) a
) b 
on a.region = b.region
```